# How to make multiple txt files with different values using cmd

Tags: cmd.exe

I'm trying to make multiple txt files with some lines changes.

I use the code below but it is not working.

```
@echo off
set line1=  ^<StartTime^>2022-11-19^</StartTime^>
set line2=  ^<Port^>8000^</Port^>
set line3=  ^<Port^>Stack Overflow^</Port^>

echo %line1% >setting.txt
echo %line2% >>setting.txt
echo %line3% >>setting.txt

set line1=%line1:2022-11-19=2022-11-18%
set line2=%line2:8000=8001%
set line3=%line2:Stack Overflow=Stack Exchange%

echo %line1% >setting1.txt
echo %line2% >>setting1.txt
echo %line3% >>setting1.txt

set line2=%line2:8001=8002%

echo %line1% >setting2.txt
echo %line2% >>setting2.txt
echo %line3% >>setting2.txt

pause
```

I'm expecting that this code will make 3 txt files in the current directory. (setting.txt, setting1.txt, setting2.txt)

Each txt files must have contents below.

setting.txt

```
  ^<StartTime^>2022-11-19^</StartTime^>
  ^<Port^>8000^</Port^>
  ^<Port^>Stack Overflow^</Port^>
```

setting1.txt

```
  ^<StartTime^>2022-11-18^</StartTime^>
  ^<Port^>8001^</Port^>
  ^<Port^>Stack Exchange^</Port^>
```

setting2.txt

```
  ^<StartTime^>2022-11-18^</StartTime^>
  ^<Port^>8002^</Port^>
  ^<Port^>Stack Exchange^</Port^>
```

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 0):

#### This `cmd` script is not working

There are a couple of things that need fixing

1. Your first `set` has extra spaces in it.
2. You have an error in the second `set` line3 command.

The following is the corrected script:

```
rem @echo off
set line1=^<StartTime^>2022-11-19^</StartTime^>
set line2=^<Port^>8000^</Port^>
set line3=^<Port^>Stack Overflow^</Port^>

echo %line1% >setting.txt
echo %line2% >>setting.txt
echo %line3% >>setting.txt

set line1=%line1:2022-11-19=2022-11-18%
set line2=%line2:8000=8001%
set line3=%line3:Stack Overflow=Stack Exchange%

echo %line1% >setting1.txt
echo %line2% >>setting1.txt
echo %line3% >>setting1.txt

set line2=%line2:8001=8002%

echo %line1% >setting2.txt
echo %line2% >>setting2.txt
echo %line3% >>setting2.txt

pause
```